# How to apply old settings to Flutter's MatrixGestureDetector after restart?

Tags: flutter

I have a MatrixGestureDetector which is responsible for zooming and moving my displayed image.
When I close the app I save the _notifier.value to Preferences and load it on restart of the app, so far so good, the image is shown exactly in the way it was before the restart.

But as soon as I try to zoom again by gesture pinch, the image suddenly unexpectly resets to an identity matrix. What is wrong? It looks to me as if I forgot to save, load and apply another important setting.

```
...
  child: Center(
    child: MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
        //print(m);
        _notifier.value = m;
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _notifier,
        builder: (ctx, child) {
          return Transform(
            transform: _notifier.value,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Transform.scale(
                    scale: 1,
                    origin: Offset(_image_offset_x, _image_offset_y),
                    child: _image,
                ),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the initial Matrix (last save) and the current matrix (this run) because the matrix inside `MatrixGestureDetector`, `onMatrixUpdate` always start from `Matrix4.identity()`

```
// your _notifier (matrix value on this run)
final _notifier = ValueNotifier<Matrix4>(Matrix4.identity());

// load matrix from shared preference
final initialMatrix = await loadMatrix();

// when you try to save the matrix, multiplicate them
await saveMatrix(_notifier.value * initialMatrix);
```

And you can add the initial matrix to the `Transform`

```
...
  return Transform(
    transform: _notifier.value * initialMatrix,
    child: Center(
    ...
```

Comment: Should I remove this line then?: "_notifier.value = m;"

Comment: You should keep it~

Comment: It's cool and I will mark it as solved. Thanks very much. Do you also know how a reset function must look like, if I want to add a menu item "Reset position"? I tried to _notifier.value.setIdentity(); and _initial_matrix.setIdentity(); but the image "jumps" on first pinch after reset. :)

Comment: Oh, I found it out by myself. After such reset, I always have to call m.setIdentity() in onMatrixUpdate :)